# Display Time from Slider

Tags: swift, time, uislider

I have a Circle Slider and want to Display the dayTime in the center of it . So in the code you can see countmin is the max min of the Slider. For Hours it runs but for minutes it´s set the Time to 60 min max min Slider but i need it that set it always next to new hour to set it to null. 
Have anything an idea what i can make there that i get the correct Time from the Minutes?     11:59

Thanks for Help

```
func valueChange(_ sender: CircleSlider) {


    var countmin = Int(Double(sender.value) * 14.4)

    minutes! = countmin / 24

    hours! = countmin / 60


    print("\(minutes)min")

    print("\(hours)hou")


    self.circleTime.text = "\(hours!):\(minutes!)"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming countmin is the number of minutes, and maybe you're thinking too much about this. Also, try to avoid force unwrapping variables unless you have to.

```
func valueChange(_ sender: CircleSlider) {


    var countmin = Int(Double(sender.value) * 14.4)

    let hours:Int = countmin/60

    let minutes = countmin - (hours*60)

    print("\(minutes)min")

    print("\(hours)hou")


    self.circleTime.text = "\(hours):\(minutes)"

}
```

Comment: FYI - please do not change local UK spelling to US spelling when editing posts, @bearacude13. They are not errors.